# Troubles with goto(cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
:WriteAgain
set x= 
set /p Variables=Write your expression 
set /a x=%Variables%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto ErrorOccured
echo %x% 
goto :eof
:ErrorOccured
echo.Your expression is not valid 
goto WriteAgain
:eof
```

Greeting, It is supposed to be a simple calc, but for some reasons, when "if" works(for 1/0) it looks like "goto" doesnt(I may be mistaken here). Could you help me to solve this problem? Also I am thinking about typing error in any txt: should I use `2>txt_name.txt` after `neq 0` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`goto :eof`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) is a built-in construction to return from a subroutine (`call :subroutine`). It exits current batch file when used not in a subroutine.

  Rename the label to `end`, for example.
  Or use [`exit`](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) instead of `goto` to the end of batch file.
- For output redirection examples and syntax see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html so in  your case `echo` prints to standard output thus `>` must be used:

  ```
  echo Your expression is not valid >errlog.txt
  ```

  Some utilities indeed print the errors to STDERR and the standard `>` won't catch the messages, so `command 2>errlog.txt` should be used.

Comment: That's an interesting quirk.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put

```
goto :eof
```

Try using

```
goto eof
```

And also I am not sure but maybe the name eof is no good (Is used by CMD itself) so keep things simple and use any other name like "exit, problem, fail, etc..."

Comment: `exit` won't be a good name either as there is such a command, so the code becomes confusing; however, `:end` could be good...